# SELinux denies nginx to proxy on localhost

Tags: selinux

My current *SELinux* configuration does not allow *nginx* to connect at `localhost:5000` (when doing a proxy pass). Here is the log from *SELinux*:

```
type=AVC
msg=audit(***********.*****): avc: denied  { name_connect } for
pid=*****
comm="nginx"
dest=5000
scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
tcontext=system_u:object_r:commplex_main_port_t:s0
tclass=tcp_socket
permissive=0
```

I understand that *nginx* has the *domain* `httpd_t` which would like to be allowed to connect the *object* (resource) `commplex_main_port_t`.
But I have no idea how to change this permission.

I tried to set the `httpd_can_network_relay` and `httpd_can_network_connect` *sebool* to `true` but even after a reboot, it still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what I was trying was right :

```bash
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect true
```

I just forgot the `-P` option, which make the change persistent over reboot.

But if someone read me, I am still interested in a more specific solution, like, only allow `nginx` to connect to `localhost:5000`